# Get results from two time intervals

Tags: mysql

There is a query which brings back sales data for the last 7 days.
How to get the sales of the last 30 days as well (to see the sales for the last 7 days AND the last 30 days in the results)?

```
SELECT 
  a.row_id,
  MAX(ad.new_value) - MIN(ad.new_value) AS sales7days 
FROM
  _audit a 
  LEFT JOIN _audit_data ad 
    ON a.audit_id = ad.audit_id 
WHERE ad.col = 'sales' 
  AND a.triggered_datetime > NOW() - INTERVAL 7 DAY 
GROUP BY a.row_id 
ORDER BY sales7days DESC;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps with a `CASE` expression:

```
SELECT a.row_id
   ,  MAX(case when a.triggered_datetime > NOW() - INTERVAL 7 DAY 
               then ad.new_value else NULL end)
    - MIN(case when a.triggered_datetime > NOW() - INTERVAL 7 DAY
               then ad.new_value else NULL end) AS sales7days 
   ,  MAX(case when a.triggered_datetime > NOW() - INTERVAL 30 DAY 
               then ad.new_value else NULL end)
    - MIN(case when a.triggered_datetime > NOW() - INTERVAL 30 DAY
               then ad.new_value else NULL end) AS sales30days 
FROM  _audit a, _audit_data ad 
WHERE a.audit_id = ad.audit_id AND ad.col = 'sales' 
GROUP BY a.row_id;
```

Comment: Got wrong results for sales7days (bigger number than sales30days). Result for sales30days is correct.

Comment: sales7days brings the sum sales, so I think it subtracts 0 from MAX(new_value).

Comment: Hmmm.  Are you still doing a `LEFT JOIN`?  Try with just an `INNER JOIN`.  Might be some behavior with your data (or MySQL) I don't understand.

Comment: Got it, just need to replace the zeros in the MIN to NULL-s, because the zeros are overwriting the correct MIN value! The performance is much better than mine and Wolf5370's.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT 
  d7.row_id,
  d7.salesdays, d30.salesdays
FROM
(
  Select a.row_id, MAX(ad.new_value) - MIN(ad.new_value) AS salesdays
  From _audit a 
  LEFT JOIN _audit_data ad ON a.audit_id = ad.audit_id 
WHERE ad.col = 'sales' AND a.triggered_datetime > NOW() - INTERVAL 7 DAY 
GROUP BY a.row_id 
) d7,
(
  Select a.row_id, MAX(ad.new_value) - MIN(ad.new_value) AS salesdays
  From       _audit a 
  LEFT JOIN _audit_data ad ON a.audit_id = ad.audit_id 
WHERE ad.col = 'sales' AND a.triggered_datetime > NOW() - INTERVAL 30 DAY 
GROUP BY a.row_id 
) d30

where d7.row_id = d30.row_id
ORDER BY sales7days DESC;
```

assume you want the same row id for both - and either value to show, you may or may not want to make it inner or outer joined and/or COALESCE the value fields (don't know enough about the data).

Comment: Good results. Similar to what I have come up with, but it seems more logical and the performance is the same.